# Calling WebMethods from Business Logic Layer in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am developing an application in ASP.Net using C#. My Application is build in Three Tier Architecture. So there is a Business Logic Layer Exists. I have written am Web Method (named getBusinessVerticals) in a class called Landing_Menus.cs which resides in Business Logic Layer (under App_Code Folder). I have to make an AJAX call to get the results of the function. My Function code is as following (Landing_Menus.cs)

```
    public static class Landing_Menus
{
    static string sql_query = string.Empty;
    static DataSet result_ds = new DataSet();

    [WebMethod]
    public static Struct_Business_Verticals[] getBusinessVerticals()
    {
        List<Struct_Business_Verticals> list_bv = new List<Struct_Business_Verticals>();
        sql_query = "select * from Business_Verticals";
        result_ds = DBAccess.selectQuery(sql_query);

        for (int i = 0; i < result_ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Struct_Business_Verticals objBusniessVerticals = new Struct_Business_Verticals();
            objBusniessVerticals.Business_Verticals_ID = Convert.ToInt32(result_ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Business_Verticals_ID"].ToString());
            objBusniessVerticals.Business_Vertical_Type = result_ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Business_Vertical_Type"].ToString();
            objBusniessVerticals.Business_Vertical_Description = result_ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Business_Vertical_Description"].ToString();
            objBusniessVerticals.status = result_ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Status"].ToString();
            list_bv.Add(objBusniessVerticals);
        }

        return list_bv.ToArray();
    }
}
```

And my AJAX Call Code is as following

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "App_Code/Landing_Menus.cs/getBusinessVerticals",
        data: "",
        dataType: "JSON",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            //for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {

            //}
        },
        error: function (result,d,s) {
            alert(s);
        }
    });
});
```

But its giving me an error like "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://www.example.com/web2print/App_Code/Landing_Menus.cs/getBusinessVerticals". Please help me to get out from here. I think I am doing some mistakes in the AJAX URL. Please guide me accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web method should be in Page.aspx.cs class. Then the url you need to call is:

```
Page.aspx/YourWebMethod
```

like here for example:

http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Your url is not correct and your web method is in static class which doesn't inherit from `Page` class - it won't work. If you want to call your business layer, you can do it within the web method.

Answer (score 0):

my idea is create one method in aspx page. in that method call your business layer

while calling jquery method

url: "*.aspx/Newmethod",

Answer (score 0):

You can only call webmethods on classes exposed as a WebService. So you can not directly call the WebMethod in your BusinessLayer via Ajax.

You basically have 2 options to access your method.

- Create a web service which calls your business logic method and call that web service from your client
- Create a PageMethod as part of an existing .aspx-Page in your project. And call this from your client. A PageMethod is basically a public static method in your aspx-Page with an WebMethod-Attribute.

Hope that helps.